# Initialization of TestBed for Angular with Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I have a working setup with Karma for an Angular application. Currently I'm testing 2 different services PerformanceService and DataService, so I have 2 files, performance.service.spec.ts and data.service.spec.ts

Both files are initializing the TestBed and also configuring a MockHttp to use when testing the services.

```
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

function createResponse(body) {
  return Observable.of(
    new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: JSON.stringify(body) }))
  );
}

class MockHttp {
  get() {
    return createResponse([]);
  }
}
```

As far as I know, this can be done once, no need to do it for every single service, so I created a src/main.spec.ts and moved that code there, and removed it from the services.

Now I run the tests and it doesn´t work, I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null`

Any idea why this happens? The main.spec.ts is being executed first, so if I'm not mistaken TestBed should be initialized once we get to test the services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Our team ran into the same problem. One solution is to extract the TestBed initialization into a separate file and guard it so that it only gets initialized once:

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

export class TestBedInitializer {

    static isInitialized: Boolean = false;

    static getTestBed() {
        if(!this.isInitialized) {
            TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
            this.isInitialized = true;
        }

        return TestBed;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the initializer in the beforeAll block to get the instance of TestBed:

```
import { TestBedInitializer } from './init';

describe('YourSystemUnderTest', () => {

    let TestBed;

    beforeAll(() => {
        TestBed = TestBedInitializer.getTestBed();
    });

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [...],
        providers: [...]
    }));

    ...

});
```

The advantage to this solution is that you're not dependent on your test suites running in any particular order. This frees you up to run your suites individually or all at once without needing to make code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to the answer of bobbyg603

For **jest** users - just add the following code in **setup-jest.js**

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to create your own `MockHttp` class, as Angular has already created one: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html

An example usage would be something like this:

```
describe( 'AppleService', () => {
    let appleService: AppleService,
        response: Response;

    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            providers: [
                AppleService,
                { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
                { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
            ],
            imports: [
                HttpModule
            ]
        } )
        .compileComponents();
    } );

    it( 'getApples() should return mocked results', async(
        inject( [ Http, XHRBackend ], ( http: Http, backend: MockBackend ) => {
            backend.connections.subscribe( ( connection: MockConnection ) => {
                expect( connection.request.url.match( /\/apple$/ ) ).not.toBe( null );
                expect( connection.request.method ).toBe( RequestMethod.Get );
                connection.mockRespond( response );
            } );

            let options = new ResponseOptions( { status: 200, body: [ testApple1, testApple2 ] } );
            response = new Response( options );

            appleService = new AppleService( resourceService, http );

            appleService.getApples().subscribe( apples => {
                expect( apples ).toEqual( [ testApple1, testApple2 ] );
            } );
    } ) ) );

} );
```

`TestBed.get()` can also be used instead of the `inject()` wrapper.

Comment: Interesting to know about MockBackend, but you didn´t answer my original question about TestBed.initTestEnvironment()

Comment: is your main.spec.ts included in the karma.conf.ts preprocessors property?

Comment: https://medium.com/@laco0416/setting-up-angular-2-testing-environment-with-karma-and-webpack-e9b833befd99